# Which board game is the family Banks playing in Fresh Prince of Bel Air S4E19?

Tags: identify-this-game

I’m rewatching The Fresh Prince of Bel Air. In season 4 episode 19 “You’d Better Shop Around” the Bankses are playing a board game with cards and pawns. Carlton reads a card to Hilary asking “You’re in a department store and you find $50 on the floor. Do you pick it up?”

Does anyone know what board game they are playing?

A close up of a card is shown here:
[image: card]
A close up of the board:
[image]

Comment: I haven't watched the episode yet, but it sounds very much like [Scruples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scruples_(game)) or a close variant.

Answer (score 5):

The game was very meta, it is very likely a fictional game the writers used to set up the scene between Philip and Ashley Banks.

Ashley read the second game card:

> It's clear your teenage daughter is
> not enjoying the tedious board game being played in a forced
> family-bonding moment.

Philip then says:

> Fine. I try to encourage family time together, and this is the thanks I get. If you don't wanna play, you don't have to. Go on, get out of here!

The joke being he then learns the card is real.

I believe the board was fabricated for the scene and the two questions intended to evoke [Scruples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scruples_(game)). That game debuted in 1984, but had been doing updates every five years. That is about the same time as the episode [aired on Feb 21, 1994](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583077).